# in \thebibliography, how to change default title References to another name

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, languages

I am new at referencing and I came to a question.
I use `\thebibliography` in my code. It generates title **Reference** by default, because i use `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` and need to keep it that way for most titles. I would like to put this particular one **Referencie** instead (Slovak language). Would it be possible? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. 

Which packages have you selected in your preamble? (I'm thinking about `babel`)

Comment: welcome to TeX. SE! Do you use `babel` package, i.e. have in preamble `\usepackage[slovak]{babel}` ?

Comment: @Zarko I use `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` because most of the titles need to be in Czech language. I would like this particular one to be in Slovak though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want to show the Slovak version in Czech; you can do

```
\addto\extrasczech{\def\bibname{Referencie}\let\refname\bibname}
```

This should do the trick. It's like any other extras, explained somewhere in `babel`'s manual.

---

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\addto\extrasczech{\def\bibname{Referencie}\let\refname\bibname}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{11}
\bibitem{a} Aaa.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's great to have site members who know both Czech and Slovak (and LaTeX, and `babel`, and ...). :-)

Comment: @Mico lol, is that an irony about my `LaTeX` skills? :-D

Comment: @Martin Most likely it's Mico's attempt to (undeservedly) praise my skills...

Comment: @yo' haha, didn't notice you are czech, všcht:) thanks for help & have a good evening!

Comment: @Martin VŠCHT, ČVUT, MFF UK, choose any :)

Comment: @yo' čvut fjfi says hi :)